# Hikari doesn't read configuration from properties file in SpringBoot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

Hi I'm using Springboot and Hikari for db connection in my project.
The springboot version is 2.2.5.RELEASE and Hikari is 3.4.2. However, when I run my project, it always use Hikari  default config value rather than using values in my properties file.
Here is my properits:

```html
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=#####
spring.datasource.username=###
spring.datasource.password=###
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=4
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=300000
```

Here is my datasource in application configuration:

```html
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
@Bean
public DataSource DBDatasource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

Here is the output :
10:23:19.050 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -maxLifetime.....................1800000

10:23:19.050 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - maximumPoolSize.................10

Anything I missed ?

Comment: which database your trying to connect? In spring boot, we don't need to create any beans for DataSource by reading properties. Just add the database jars properly in pom.xml, & declare the database credentials in application.properties

Comment: I connect to sql db.

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the default DataSource auto configuration. Here's how you can properly intialize hikari datasource:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
HikariDataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
    HikariDataSource dataSource = properties
       .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
       .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    if (StringUtils.hasText(properties.getName())) {
        dataSource.setPoolName(properties.getName());
    }
    return dataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out just need to config in properties file without 'hikari' :

spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=4